# Simple JavaScript to access selected value of a select element/dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, drop-down-menu, listbox

I know how to get value/text of the selected item in a drop down:

```
document.getElementById('selNames').options[document.getElementById('selNames').selectedIndex].value
```

AND

```
document.getElementById('selNames').options[document.getElementById('selNames').selectedIndex].text
```

This is really big code. So I have created a function named "$$" which eases this quite:

```
function $$(id) { return document.getElementById(id) }
```

And using it as following to retrieve value and text respectively:

```
$$('selNames').options[$$('selNames').selectedIndex].value
$$('selNames').options[$$('selNames').selectedIndex].text
```

But I further want to minimize this code as following:

```
$$('selNames').val
$$('selNames').text
```

I know jQuery too but I don't want to use it because sometimes I don't require that much functionality that jQuery is providing and to use lesser file size for faster loading of page resources.

So, how do I make the "$$" object that can act as I want?

Comment: Try HTML DOM your work will become hell lot of easier

Comment: @Quasarthespacething, please can you explain more, I didn't get your point. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function $$(id) { 
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    return {
        element: el,
        get val() {
            return el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;
        },
        get text() {
        return el.options[el.selectedIndex].text;
        }
    };
}
```

If you're not averse to some prototype fiddling, you can use this:

```
HTMLSelectElement.prototype.__defineGetter__("val", function() { return this.options[this.selectedIndex].value; });
HTMLSelectElement.prototype.__defineGetter__("text", function() { return this.options[this.selectedIndex].text; });
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/Ynb8j/

Comment: That’s better (for the `$$` function anyway). I’d recommend against the `__defineGetter__` approach: prototype fiddling is a bit of a dirty trick, it’s non-standard, and it’s also [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineGetter).

Comment: @Martijn It isn't prototype fiddling that is deprecated, it is that particular syntax for fiddling with the prototype. It is entirely possible to add getters to the prototype without using `defineGetter`

Comment: @Asad: you’re right, I didn’t express myself clearly.
I’d recommend against the `__defineGetter__` approach: it’s non-standard and deprecated; and I’d recommend against prototype fiddling in any case since it’s a bit of a dirty trick. That said, it can come in handy at times.

Comment: The prototyping using `__defineGetter__` is not working in IE9.

Comment: @BNikunj Yes, that is because it is non standard. Use the first approach suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Asad.
From your script, I extended to cover more features. Here it is on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/JD2J8/) and below:

```
<script>
function $$(id, optValue) { 
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    return {
        element: el,
        get text() {
            return el.options[el.selectedIndex].text;
        },
        get value() {
            if(el.type == 'select-one' || el.type == 'select-multiple')
                return el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;
            else
                return el.value;
        },
        get html() {
            return el.innerHTML
        },
        set html(newValue) {
            el.innerHTML = newValue;
        },
        set text(newText) {
            if(optValue == undefined)
                optValue = el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;
            for(i=0; i<el.length; i++)
                if(el.options[i].value == optValue)
                    el.options[i].text = newText;
        },
        set value(newValue) {
            if(el.type == 'select-one' || el.type == 'select-multiple')
            {   if(optValue == undefined)
                    el.options[el.selectedIndex].value = newValue;
                else
                    for(i=0; i<el.length; i++)
                        if(el.options[i].value == optValue)
                            el.options[i].value = newValue;
            }
            else
                el.value = newValue;
        }
    };
}

function f1() { $$('sel1').text = $$('txt1').value }
function f2() { $$('txt2').value = $$('sel1').text }
function f3() { $$('sel2',($$('txt3').value == '' ? undefined : $$('txt3').value)).value = $$('txt4').value }
function f4() { $$('span1').html = $$('txt5').value }
function f5() { $$('txt6').value = $$('span1').html }
</script>

text: <input id='txt1' /> <input type='button' value='set text' onclick='f1()' /> 
<select id="sel1">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>
<input type='button' value='get text' onclick='f2()' /> <input id='txt2' />
<hr />

current value: <input id='txt3' />, new value: <input id='txt4' /> <input type='button' value='set value' onclick='f3()' /> 
<select id="sel2">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>
<hr />

text: <input id='txt5' /> <input type='button' value='set html' onclick='f4()' /> <span id='span1'>span</span>
<input type='button' value='get html' onclick='f5()' /> <input id='txt6' />
<hr />
```

I will try the prototype method later. I am just concerned about its compatibility with older browsers.

Comment: Please remove the new question from your answer and update the error you made. Otherwise, you that it will get deleted...

Comment: As I prefer different approach of curly bracing style, I tried changing the style but it was throwing an exception "`SyntaxError: missing ; before statement`" at line 6 (at `get text()`) in Firebug. You can find the source [here](http://techwheels.net/extra/minijs.htm).

The problem is at the return statement. The curly brace must be at the end in the return statement. The corrected code is [here](http://techwheels.net/extra/minijs2.htm).